# Assigning higher weights to more recent observations in a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python

I have time-series data and am using a Neural Network for the purposes of forecasting forward. I have 20 years of monthly data but would like to assign a higher weight to those observations that have occurred more recently (like in the last 1 year) in the parameter estimation process, as I believe that this data will have a bigger influence on projections. Would the Neural Network be able to capture the fact that the more recent data is having a bigger influence on future estimates or would I have to explicitly feed it this information? If so, how could I look to do this in python?

Comment: This is a common question, but I would argue misguided.if you believe your data is non stationary then you should model time, not create some ad-hoc reweighting

Comment: @seanv507 That makes sense. To understand, then wouldn't exponential smoothing, which is used to assign decreasing weights over time, also be subject to same non-stationarity issues?